# Reverting mechanisms in Salt

Tags: deployment, version-control, salt-stack

I'm using Salt for my project deployment. What if the deployment is unsuccessful? Does any mechanism for reverting exist in Salt?

By reverting, I mean that I want to be able to revert my database and my system to the most recent working state.

Answer (score 0):

As far I can tell Salt does not provide virtualization AND/OR snapshot capabilities out of box.

However, Salt state definitions are idempotent, meaning they describe final state and are safe to apply multiple times. Note, that it helps only in case something has been broken in the middle, then the fix is just to retry the state, e.g.

`salt minion state.sls mystate`

Having said that, if youn seek for some kind of recovery/failover guarantee - there are several ways how to skin the rabbit.

- I have no experience in this particular area, so I might be wrong, however I believe SaltStack integrates with Docker and different containerization technologies. So, one way would be to build your failover procedure on top of that.
- If your target platform is Cloud (AWS, DigitalOcean etc..) you might adjust you topology in the way you spin new instances from snapshots, perform salt state updates, perform smoke/sanity tests, register instances in LoadBalancer etc... If any of those states fails - no big deal, restart later.